# git filter-branch rm wildcard for a specific target folder

Tags: git

I have a directory named packages immediately under my git repository (**root/packages/files here**) and another with the same name in some other subfolder(**root/directory1/packages/files here**). I want to make sure that everything in the former is removed and the latter stays as is. Is this command going to match both? If yes, what can I do to make sure only **root/packages/all files** is targeted by git rm?

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch packages/*' --prune-empty HEAD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is an `--index-filter` and not a `--tree-filter`, it's wisest to protect the glob character `*` from the shell.<sup>1</sup>  That is:

```
git filter-branch \
    --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "packages/*"' \
    ...
```

for instance.  (In a `--tree-filter`, `*` will behave in the usual expected way.)  This leaves the `*` glob expansion up to Git, which will match only names in the directory named `packages/` as stored in the index.  (That's what you say you want.)

As [the `git rm` documentation notes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html), this will match directory names as well.  It won't *remove* those directories, due to the lack of `-r`, but it will still match them.  If there are no such directories this will not be an issue.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `filter-branch` command runs each filter in a temporary directory, so most shells under most settings wind up leaving the `*` un-expanded and do the right thing anyway.

Note that if you are using a `--tree-filter`, the temporary directory has a copy of the tree being filtered.  Otherwise, it is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Accepting as answer for the glob expansion details :) It does match exactly what i need.